# Decoding a Trap - "Index Out of Range" Message in WinBUGS

Tags: r, winbugs, r2winbugs, winbugs14

I've been tasked with re-running someone else's model with updated data (I did the data update and formatting). I understand how the model works but didn't write it, and it's quite long and detailed. On top of that, I exclusively use JAGS and this is my first time wading into WinBUGS, so the interface and error messages are new to me. The model takes two days to compile (and it does compile), but then I get a Trap error that says Index Out of Range followed by a few dozen lines that are unintelligible to me. I've gone over the entire model, for-loops, and data structure and I can't see where there are any indexing issues. And, frustratingly, unlike JAGS, WinBUGS does not appear to tell you which index is out of range.

I'd greatly appreciate any assistance decoding the Trap error message, in case there's more information in there than I realize to specify the location of the index mismatch. I'm going to post the model below, along with the trap message, but I don't see the point in posting the actual data as no one is going to spend 2 days waiting for the model to compile in order to reproduce the error. Instead I'll just post the data structure so the dimensions of each data object are obvious.

A few considerations: I'm using the exact model that was previously used (literally copied and pasted), so I know that it ought to work. The previous data files are in rectangular format, whereas the ones I've created and exported are in S format. My understanding is that WinBUGS should be able to handle both, but am wondering if that might be part of the problem. I'm running the model directly from WinBUGS, loading model and data files manually. I tried doing it from R with r2winbugs previously but was getting memory errors and crashes.

Model:

```
model{

  for(i in 1:n+nzeros){ # loop through the observed and unobserved areas
    for(j in 1:J){  #loop through the J fisheries areas 
      for(t in 1:T){ # loop through the years

        y[i,j,t] ~ dpois(mu.y[i,j,t])
        mu.y[i,j,t] <- lambda[i,j,t]*x[i,t]

        log(lambda[i,j,t]) <- mu.lambda[j]+ theta[z[i],j] + e.lambda[j,t] 

      }}}

  for(i in 1:n+nzeros){

    x[i,1] ~ dbern(gamma[i,1])
    recruitable[i,1]<-1

    for(t in 2:T){
      x[i,t] ~ dbern(mu.x[i,t])
      mu.x[i,t] <- survived[i,t] + gamma[i,t]*recruitable[i,t]
      recruitable[i,t] <- recruitable[i,t-1]*(1-x[i,t-1])
      survived[i,t] <- x[i,t-1]*phi[i,t-1]
    }}


  #priors

  for(c in 1:C){
    theta[c,1:J] ~ dmnorm(mu.th[], tau.th[,])

    for(j in 1:J){
      lcapture.clus[c,j]<-mu.lambda[j]+theta[c,j]
      pcapture.clus[c,j]<-1-exp(-exp(lcapture.clus[c,j]))
    }
  }

  for(j in 1:J){
    mu.th[j] <-0
    mu.lambda[j]~dnorm(0, 0.001)
    pcapture.overall[j]<-1-exp(-exp(mu.lambda[j]))

    for (t in 1:T){
      e.lambda[j,t] ~ dnorm(0, tau.e)
      lambda.area[j,t]<-mu.lambda[j]+e.lambda[j,t]
      p.area[j,t]<-1-exp(-exp(lambda.area[j,t]))
      #n.area[j,t]~dbin(p.area[j,t],N.area[j,t])
      N.area[j,t]<-n.area[j,t]/p.area[j,t]

      #N.area[j,t] ~ dunif(n.area[j,t],500)
      #N.area.round[j,t]<-round(N.area[j,t])
    }}



  tau.e <- 1/(sd.e*sd.e)
  sd.e ~ dunif(0,10)

  tau.th[1:J, 1:J] ~ dwish(B[,], v)
  sigma2[1:J, 1:J] <- inverse(tau.th[1:J,1:J])
  v<-J

  for(j1 in 1:J){
    B[j1,j1]<-1
    for(j2 in 1:j1-1){
      B[j1,j2]<-0
    }
    for(j2 in j1+1:J){
      B[j1,j2]<-0
    }
    for(j2 in 1:J){
      pd[j1,j2] <- step(sigma2[j1,j2])
    }}

  for(i in 1:n+nzeros){
    for(t in 1:T-1){
      logit(phi[i,t]) <- logit(mu.phi) + e.phi[z.cut[i],t]
    }

    gamma[i,1]~dunif(0,1)

    for(t in 2:T){
      logit(gamma[i,t]) <-logit(mu.gamma) + e.gamma[z.cut[i],t]
    }}

  for(c in 1:C){
    for (t in 1:T-1){ 
      e.phi[c,t] ~ dnorm(0, tau.phi)
      prob.phi[c,t]<-step(e.phi[c,t])
    }

    for(t in 2:T){
      e.gamma[c,t] ~ dnorm(0, tau.gamma)
    }}

  mu.gamma ~ dunif(0,1)
  tau.gamma <- 1/(sd.gamma*sd.gamma)
  sd.gamma ~ dunif(0,10)

  mu.phi ~ dunif(0,1)
  tau.phi <- 1/(sd.phi*sd.phi)
  sd.phi ~ dunif(0,10)


  # Clustering
  for(i in 1:n+nzeros){

    z[i] ~ dcat(w[])
    z.cut[i]<-cut(z[i]) 
    for(c in 1:C){
      post.prob[i,c] <- equals(z[i],c)}}
  for(c in 1:C){
    w[c] <- ww[c]/sum(ww[])
    r[c] ~ dbeta(1,a)
    NC[c] <- sum(post.prob[,c])
    cl[c] <- step(NC[c]-1)} 
  ww[1] <- r[1]
  for(c in 2:C){
    ww[c] <- r[c]*(1-r[c-1])*ww[c-1]/r[c-1]}          
  CLUSTERS <- sum(cl[])
  a<- 1 # controls prior smoothing


  #derived parameters
  for(i in 1:n+nzeros){
    for(c in 1:C){
      recruit[i,c,1]<-x[i,1]*equals(z[i],c)
      for(t in 2:T){
        recruit[i,c,t]<-(1-x[i,t-1])*(x[i,t])*equals(z[i],c)
        death[i,c,t] <- x[i,t-1]*(1-x[i,t])*equals(z[i],c)
        alive[i,c,t]<-x[i,t]*equals(z[i],c)
      }}}

  for(c in 1:C){
    for(t in 2:T){
      R[c,t]<-sum(recruit[1:n+nzeros,c,t])
      D[c,t]<-sum(death[1:n+nzeros,c,t])
      N[c,t]<-sum(alive[1:n+nzeros,c,t])
      Rpc[c,t]<-R[c,t]/N[c,t]
      recruitment.clus[c,t]<- exp(logit(mu.gamma) + e.gamma[c,t])/(1+exp(logit(mu.gamma) + e.gamma[c,t]))
    }

    for(t in 1:T-1){
      survival.clus[c,t] <- exp(logit(mu.phi) + e.phi[c,t])/(1+exp(logit(mu.phi) + e.phi[c,t]))
    }}

  for(t in 2:T){
    NN[t]<-sum(N[1:C, t])
    DD[t]<-sum(D[1:C, t])
    RR[t]<-sum(R[1:C, t])
    RRpc[t]<-RR[t]/NN[t]
  }

  #partitioned p values

  for (i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:J){
      for (t in 1:T){
        y.new[i,j,t]~dpois(mu.y[i,j,t])


        # for predictive goodness of fit

        p0[i,j,t] <- equals(y[i,j,t],0)
        p0new[i,j,t]<-equals(y.new[i,j,t],0)

        count[i,j,t]<-y[i,j,t]
        countnew[i,j,t]<-y.new[i,j,t]

        for (c in 1:C){

          d.p0[i,j,t,c]<-p0[i,j,t]*equals(z[i],c)
          d.p0new[i,j,t,c]<-p0new[i,j,t]*equals(z[i],c)

          d.count[i,j,t,c]<-count[i,j,t]*equals(z[i],c)
          d.countnew[i,j,t,c]<-countnew[i,j,t]*equals(z[i],c)

        }}}}
  for(j in 1:J){
    for(t in 1:T){
      for(c in 1:C){
        fit1.p0[j,t,c] <- sum(d.p0[1:n,j,t,c])
        fit.new1.p0[j,t,c] <- sum(d.p0new[1:n,j,t,c])

        fit1.count[j,t,c] <- sum(d.count[1:n,j,t,c])
        fit.new1.count[j,t,c] <- sum(d.countnew[1:n,j,t,c])
      }}}

  for(t in 1:T){
    for(c in 1:C){
      fit2.p0[t,c] <- sum(fit1.p0[1:J,t,c])
      fit.new2.p0[t,c] <- sum(fit.new1.p0[1:J,t,c])

      fit2.count[t,c] <- sum(fit1.count[1:J,t,c])
      fit.new2.count[t,c] <- sum(fit.new1.count[1:J,t,c])
    }}

  for(c in 1:C){
    DF.p0[c] <- sum(fit2.p0[,c])
    DF.new.p0[c] <- sum(fit.new2.p0[,c])
    pvalue.p0[c] <- step(DF.new.p0[c] - DF.p0[c])

    DF.count[c] <- sum(fit2.count[,c])
    DF.new.count[c] <- sum(fit.new2.count[,c])
    pvalue.count[c] <- step(DF.new.count[c] - DF.count[c])
  }

  DFoverall.p0<-sum(DF.p0[1:C])
  DFoverall.new.p0<-sum(DF.new.p0[1:C])
  pvalueoverall.p0<-step(DFoverall.new.p0-DFoverall.p0)


  DFoverall.count<-sum(DF.count[1:C])
  DFoverall.new.count<-sum(DF.new.count[1:C])
  pvalueoverall.count<-step(DFoverall.new.count-DFoverall.count)

}
```

Input data (I did all of the data formatting in R, so I compile this as a list and then export it with r2winbugs in S/R format, so presumably it should work in WinBUGS):

```
bugs.data <- list(y = y, 
              x = x.data,
              J = dim(y)[2],
              T = dim(y)[3],
              n = dim(y)[1]-100, 
              nzeros = 100, 
              C = 10,
              n.area = n.area)
```

Data Structure (and I confirmed these manually in the actual text file):

```
> dim(y)
[1] 727   7  41
> dim(x.data)
[1] 727  41
> dim(n.area)
[1]  7 41
> J
[1] 7
> T
[1] 41
> n
[1] 627
```

And finally the Trap error:

```
index out of range

 HostWindows.AppendInt   [000002B7H] 
    .d  ARRAY 12 OF CHAR    "080'069'784'"
    .i  INTEGER 12
    .j  INTEGER 1971081876
    .len    INTEGER 1971172856
    .n  INTEGER 1
    .s  ARRAY 256 OF CHAR   " Allocated Memory: "   ...
    .useSeparators  BOOLEAN TRUE
 HostWindows.UpdateInfo   [000048B8H] 
    .res    INTEGER 2291852
    .sstr   ARRAY 256 OF SHORTCHAR  "l˜""   ...
    .str    ARRAY 256 OF CHAR   " Allocated Memory: "   ...
 HostWindows.Idle   [00004A73H] 
    .focus  BOOLEAN FALSE
    .tick   Controllers.TickMsg Fields
    .w  HostWindows.Window  NIL
 HostMenus.TimerTick   [00003422H] 
    .lParam INTEGER 0
    .ops    Controllers.PollOpsMsg  Fields
    .wParam INTEGER 1
    .wnd    INTEGER 459558
 Kernel.Try   [00003A61H] 
    .a  INTEGER 459558
    .b  INTEGER 1
    .c  INTEGER 0
    .h  PROCEDURE   HostMenus.TimerTick
 HostMenus.ApplWinHandler   [00003841H] 
    .Proc   PROCEDURE   NIL
    .hit    BOOLEAN Undefined117
    .lParam INTEGER 0
    .message    INTEGER 275
    .res    INTEGER 2292416
    .s  ARRAY 256 OF SHORTCHAR  9AX, 4X, 0CX   ...
    .w  INTEGER 0
    .wParam INTEGER 1
    .wnd    INTEGER 459558
<system>   (pc=757CC4E6H,  fp=0022FB3CH)
<system>   (pc=757CC5E6H,  fp=0022FBB4H)
<system>   (pc=757CCC18H,  fp=0022FC14H)
<system>   (pc=757C2E40H,  fp=0022FC24H)
 HostMenus.Loop   [00003BDEH] 
    .done   BOOLEAN FALSE
    .f  SET {0..5}
    .n  INTEGER 10
    .res    INTEGER 0
    .w  HostWindows.Window  NIL
 Kernel.Start   [00002B8CH] 
    .code   PROCEDURE   HostMenus.Loop
```

Thanks a ton in advance for your help! -Josh

Comment: Would it be possible to try the model with a subset of the data, with the same structure?  You might be able to explore whether it really is an indexing issue, and not have to wait for days between tries.  For that matter, you might even be able to try the model in JAGS.

Comment: My original plan was to just run it in JAGS, but unfortunately there are a few functions in there that didn't carry over in the transfer from WinBUGS to JAGS, and it would require a major rewrite. I can definitely try running it with a subset of the data, that's an interesting idea. Does WinBUGS sometimes throw up indexing errors when there is a different underlying problem? I previously tried running this directly from r2winbugs and got memory errors, which is why I switched to running it manually in the GUI. So maybe that's still an issue.

Comment: That looks like some other than R language (perhaps Fortran?) messages rather than R messages.

Comment: Yeah the error is direct from WinBUGS, which was made with BlackBox (not sure what the underlying language is). This is tagged as 'r' because WinBUGS is commonly run via R. But the error is coming directly from WinBUGs, as opposed to from R.

Comment: Have you reviewed all hits for SO or google searches on `[winbugs] index out of range`? Reading your comment on the possibility of porting to JAGS, I also wonder if using OpenBUGS might be explored.

Comment: Went through all of the google hits before posting on here :-\ and I also get the same error in OpenBUGS! I have a modified version running in JAGS, but it loses some of the functionality as not everything carried over from WinBUGS to JAGS. But it did convince me that it's not a true index out of range, as I'm using the same data and the exact same for-loops in the JAGS code. Unfortunately I think I may be out of luck!